# NodeJS NPM issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I can't install any packages from npm.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\myApps\mobileApp\shym\npm-debug.log
```

npm config get proxy -> null

npm config get https-proxy -> null

npm config get registery -> registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

Comment: This appears to be a problem with your internet connection.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670317/npm-command-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be behind a proxy in order to install dependency you must configure npm to connect to your proxy, by doing

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:3000
npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.example.com:3000`
```

in your terminal.