# npm command issue

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

- I have installed node js on my system. (Windows 7).
- I have set the environment path variable to
  `"C:\Users\pUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm"`.
- There one .npmrc file in users folder. Which has values set for https_proxy,proxy,registry.
- I try to check the node version and npm version as follows:
- a.  D:\Pooja Project\project-sd-develop-12>node -v
        output -->v6.9.4
- b.  D:\Pooja Project\project-sd-develop-12>npm -v (Does not show any result)

  It doesn't respond at all for npm command.Neither any output nor any error.
  ( It is not even showing any success or error message.)
  The screen shot attached npm command gets stuck no futher result or any error
  [image]
  Am I missing any step?

Comment: Where you have installed npm? Open that folder in cmd and try npm -v

Comment: Issue resolved. By running where npm I got all the paths for npm folder. Then I have uninstalled the node js from my system and deleted the npm folder wherever possible. Freshly installed node js and now it is working. . @Suresh thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the wrong environment path.
It should be:

```
C:\Users\pUser\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

not the `npm` inside `node_modules`

If Still you are facing the same issue then.
By running `where npm` yOu will get all the paths for npm folder. Then uninstall the node js from your system and delete the npm folder wherever possible. Freshly installed node js.

Comment: Not working for me. No response or result for npm command at all.

Comment: Thanks @suraj. Not working for me. No response or result for npm command at all. Initially it was working I don't all of sudden what went wrong. Ihave reinstalled the node js still facing same issue.Is it becuase I have reinstalled the node js?

Comment: what is the output of `where npm`

Comment: did you restart your command prompt after correcting env variable?

Comment: This the output for where npm
C:\Users\pUser\AppData\Roaming\npm>where npm
C:\Users\pUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\pUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

Comment: Issue resolved. By running where npm I got all the paths for npm folder. Then I have uninstalled the node js from my system and deleted the npm folder wherever possible. Freshly installed node js and now it is working. @surja thanks